# How to fil an array from id in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multidimensional-array, nsarray

**i'm using PHP File to retrieve Data as an Array in xcode**.. it was working fine until the Data became more the one row.. it's keep giving me error at run time.. i hope if u can help.. i'm very new to these issues and i'm self studying..
the php file :

```
 ...
     while($row= mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
       $Data[] = array(
           "Student_Mark"  => $row[0],
           "Course_number" =>$row[1],
           "Course_Name"=>$row[2]
        );
```

i defined 3 arrays in the .m

```
    @implementation vcMarks
{
    NSArray *arrCourse;
    NSArray *arrCrsName;
    NSArray *arrMark;
}
```

then to retrieve data from the PHP file i will write the last part.

```
        id jd = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", jd);
        arrCourse = [[jd objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Course_number"] ;
        arrCrsName = [[jd objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Course_name"] ;
```

the first problem in this situation it always give only one value.

the second problem her  at run time..

```
  - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    @try
    {

    CustomCell3 *cell = (CustomCell3 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[CustomCell3 reuseIdentifier]];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell3" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = _customcell3;
        _customcell3 = nil;
    }

    cell.lbl1.text = [arrCourse objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.lbl2.text = [arrCrsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbl1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.lbl1.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
}
}
```

**thanks for your patience and help in advance**.. if you could send me some links that will help i will be great full..

Comment: You should check your jsondata. Whether it is returning proper array values or not?

Comment: thanks for answering @san .. yes i check, it returns data and in all Output : (
        {
        "Course_Name" = 70;
        "Course_number" = 1301301;
        "Student_Mark" = "VB.NET";
    },
        {
        "Course_Name" = 90;
        "Course_number" = 407101;
        "Student_Mark" = markting;
    },
        {
        "Course_Name" = 80;
        "Course_number" = 402445;
        "Student_Mark" = managment;
    },
        {
        "Course_Name" = "-";
        "Course_number" = 130132;
        "Student_Mark" = Complier;
    }
)

Comment: thank you soooo much @san it worked perfectly.. but i need your help in another issue if you could... for the function numberofRowInSection how can i get i dynamically??     -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 6;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
cell.lbl1.text = [[jd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Course_number"] ;
cell.lbl2.text = [[jd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Course_name"];
```

You have to keep a reference to your variable `jd`

```
arrCourse = [[jd objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Course_number"] ;
```

Above line returns single value because `[jd objectAtIndex:0]` returns a dictionary which then returns the value for key `Course_number`

Comment: thank you soooo much @san it worked perfectly.. but i need your help in another issue if you could... for the function numberofRowInSection how can i get i dynamically??     -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 6;
}

Comment: thanks @san,, but i solved the issue.. thanks for your concern :)

Comment: Welcome. :-) Please accept the answer if it worked for you. ;-)